# FileDB: a key/value NoSQL fast disk storage, in Ruby

Tags: ruby, caching, filesystems, key-value-store, nosql

I ask a suggestion about how to persist hash data structure to disk, in Ruby, (possibly using a simple/pure Ruby solution on Linux OS).

I'm coding a chatbot dialog server and

1. server must access sessions that are small data structures (hashes), where a  `session` is something like:

   ```
   def to_hash
     { dialog: @dialog, data: @data, updated_at: timestamp_now }
   end
   ```
2. The server maintain in memory a key-value hash sessions storage:

   ```
   :giorgio => {:dialog=>"Cart#cart_action", :data=>{:cart=>["1 pizza Capresina", "2 pizze 4 Stagioni", "2 lattine di coca-cola"]}, :updated_at=>"2016-10-11T10:57:58Z"}
   :paola => {:dialog=>"Cart#cart_action", :data=>{:cart=>["5 pizze Capricciosa con aggiunta di  acciughe", "2 birre medie chiare alla spina"]}, :updated_at=>"2016-10-07T17:17:21Z"}
   ```

This data structure could be just a Ruby hash of  `session` or it could be better managed as a thread safe LRU cache like [lru_redux](https://github.com/SamSaffron/lru_redux).

3. My problem is how to persist these data (sessions) to disk. I'd like to manage sessions in memory with a cache (expiring with a time to live setting) and maintaing a disk persistence at the same time, having multiple threads and multiple process to access storage (disk data).

Some solutions:
- allow hash data persistence with any NoSQL db, e.g. MongoDB 
- using Postgresql specific features to fast unstructured data as HSTORE oor JSONB
- use a REDIS db.
- use key/value disk libraries as [levelDB](https://www.sitepoint.com/leveldb-ruby/) or new [rocksdb](http://rocksdb.org/) from Facebook:

Proposal/opinion:
My naif gist could be to use just the file system storage to serialize/unserialize memory data, e.g. storing each session data on a dedicated file containing specific data stored with standard Ruby marshalling/unmarshalling (or other fast portable fast serialization as [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) ). In that way each data correspond to a single file and the read/write access is almost costant and indipendent from the numbers of records.

The minus of this solution is that databases is composed by a huge number of data files.

Any idea ?

Comment: Some filesystems perform poorly when you create a large number of files in a dir.

Comment: ProTip: To have code snippets show up properly in a list, indent them with 8 spaces.

Comment: btw, I'm interested mainly in linux